# Is it possible to perform calculations with static primitives using Rust's macros / syntax extensions?

Tags: macros, static, metaprogramming, rust

I'm curious as to whether it is possible to perform compile time calculations on static primitives that return other static primitives.

For example, something like this:

```
static FOUR: uint = add!(2u, 2u);
static FORTY_TWO: f32 = div!(84f32, 2f32);

static CHANNELS: uint = 2;
static FRAMES: uint = 256;
static BUFFER_SIZE: uint = mul!(CHANNELS, FRAMES);
```

If it is possible, how would one approach this?

Comment: It’s totally possible for literals, as you have the tokens, but I don’t know how possible it’ll be for non-literals.

Comment: Ahhh my apologies, I didn't realise I could just use the basic operators! Thanks.

Comment: Whoa, I also was so busy thinking of macros that I forgot the basic operators worked in that context. `static BUFFER_SIZE: uint = CHANNELS * FRAMES;` works just fine.

Comment: Note that for constant values you should use `const` instead of `static`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, they are evaluated at compile time without the need to write macros nor syntax extensions.

As proof, the following code:

```
static FOUR: uint = 2u + 2u;
static FORTY_TWO: f32 = 84f32 / 2f32;

static CHANNELS: uint = 2;
static FRAMES: uint = 256;
static BUFFER_SIZE: uint = CHANNELS * FRAMES;
```

results in this LLVM IR:

```
@_ZN4FOUR20h8a0d12679f3ae402gaaE = internal constant i64 4
@_ZN9FORTY_TWO20h4316db579aa4eb4fmaaE = internal constant float 4.200000e+01
@_ZN8CHANNELS20h8a0d12679f3ae402saaE = internal constant i64 2
@_ZN6FRAMES20h8a0d12679f3ae402waaE = internal constant i64 256
@_ZN11BUFFER_SIZE20h8a0d12679f3ae402AaaE = internal constant i64 512
```

Hope it helped.